# Sticky footer on fixed position sidebar, want css solution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I used the technique of sticky footer provided [by Martin Bean and Ryan Fait](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) for a while, works fine until I find myself needs to put a sticky footer on a fixed position sidebar.

Since fixed position sidebar is invisible to the document, the setting of margin and padding in the wrapper has no effect.  I tried to add another inner-wrapper inside the sidebar but also not helping.  I would like to know if there's any pure CSS solution for this request?

The reason I have to use fixed positioning sidebar is I use transitioning effect to collapse it when screen size is small.  The method is learned from StartBootstrap, example simple-sidebar.

BTW:  I'm using BS3

The basic set up of my site is:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">   
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div id="inner-wrap">
      <ul id="sidebar-nav">
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      Copyright claim
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div id="main-wrapper">
    Some Content
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 auto 50px;
  margin: 0 auto -50px;
}

#inner-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -50px;
  padding: 0 auto 50px;
  width: 100%; 
}

#sidebar-nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#footer {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
}
```

I made a temp [bootply](http://bootply.com/89202).  Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**
The problem is solved by Bass. Thanks a lot!  The cause of the above code not working is due to the extra 'height: auto !important;' set in the parent #sidebar-wrapper.  Delete it then everything works fine.  If you like, you can also delete the position:absolute in #footer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems to me you can do the same with an extra wrapper on your sidebar:

**html**

```
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
   <div id="sidebar-wrapper-wrapper">     
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shortcuts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:red;height:60px">footer</div>  

  </div>
```

**css**

```
#sidebar-wrapper-wrapper {
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto -60px;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 60px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Bass, the difference of your answer from mine is you put the extra wrapper (#sidebar-wrapper-wrapper in your answer, #inner-wrapper in mine) outside the footer and also inside the sidebar-wrapper.  It does not works that the sticky footer is still under the <ul> but not sticky to the bottom in a larger screen.  The reason is the same, that the extra wrapper only gets the full height of <ul>, but not the parent #sidebar-wrapper.  Any further idea?

Comment: I edit my question to move the #inner-wrapper outside the #footer, save other's time to point out the same solution.

Comment: It works!  Seems the 'height: auto !important;' set in the parent #sidebar-wrapper cause the footer float under the <ul>.  Once del it the footer is stick to the bottom.  Don't know why, any idea?

Comment: can't see any useful comment there, they are talking about IE hack which I think is irrelevant.  Anyway, thanks.